# Lubuntu 14.04 + TightVNC: remote mouse cursor is "X"

Tags: lubuntu, mouse, vnc, tightvncserver

I am connecting from my Windows 7 machine to my Lubuntu 14.04 server using TightVNC. Everything is working as expected except the remote mouse cursor only displays as an "X".

[image: screenshot]

My `./vnc/xstartup` file is configured as follows:

```
#!/bin/sh

xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
xsetroot -solid grey
autocutsel -fork
lxsession -s Lubuntu -e LXDE
```

and to set up TightVNC on the server, I installed the following packages:

- lubuntu-desktop
- tightvncserver
- autocutsel

Do I need to install a package to get the remote mouse cursor to show up correcting when using TightVNC? Do I need to add a command to my `xstartup` file?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

After researching into each command used in my `xstartup` file and the options available, I found the solution to be adding the following parameters to `xsetroot`:

```
-cursor_name left_ptr
```

So, my `xstartup` file now looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
xsetroot -solid grey -cursor_name left_ptr
autocutsel -fork
lxsession -s Lubuntu -e LXDE
```

[image: screenshot]